# Django's two way relationship workrounds

Tags: django

In mysql there are two tables which has `many-to-man`y relationship, and linked by an intermediate table with foreign keys. When I used Django's `inspectdb` to create models, the model is as raw as mysql, which has no `many-to-many` relationship literally.

I think this model is clean. Though it has no direct `many-to-many`, I can use the intermediate table for mutual lookup, e.g.

`t2_object[]=SELECT* FROM intermediate_table WHERE t1.id=2;
SELECT* FROM t2 WHEREt2_id IN t2_object[]`

But in this way performance may be compromised. I guess some ORM such as Hibernate uses such approach to provide two-way object persistence.

What's best practices to deal with `many-to-many` in Django? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. All m2m relationships involve a through table. Django doesn't know that your specific table is actually a through table, but you do, so you can just add the ManyToManyField manually, surely.

Comment: The models.py was generated by "python manage.py inspectdb" from mysql.

Comment: So? You can still edit it.